# How to check if the final destination file of a soft link actually exists or not?

Tags: linux, shell, ls

1) How to check if the final destination file of a soft link actually exists or not ?

<strike>2) `ls –ltr` shows permission, user, group, size, date time, name etc. what command would you use if you want to see only the name column (nothing else, without `grep` or `awk` command)</strike>

Comment: This should be on superuser stack exchange. Also, this is two separate questions.

Comment: For #2 please read the manual page for `ls`. For #1 you can use a `test` command. See the documentation.

Comment: `test -f` works. returns `0` on regular files and nondangling links to regular files and `1` otherwise. And it's quick cuz it's a builtin. Alternatively there's `test -r` which checks for readability by you, in addition to existence. I think that should match your request more closely. See `help test` for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How to check if the final destination file of a soft link actually
>   exists or not ?

To achieve this with simple linux commands you can use `stat -L`, this will throw an error if the destination file does not exists.
Also this command will return `0` if the destination file exists or `>0` if it doesn't. So you can use `echo $?` after using it and check if it is not 0.

> 2) ls –ltr shows permission, user, group, size, date time, name etc. what command would you use if you want to see only the name column (nothing else, without grep or awk command)

You can just type `ls -1` to get file names alone.

Comment: Hi Durga .. Thanks for your comment..

Comment: for 2)  , it is fine .... but 1) stat is still not working :(

Comment: got it ...thanks again :)